# Oracle SQL Developer : change colour themes by connection

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I wonder if there's a way to specify Oracle SQL Developer themes by connection.

I explain, we work on many environments : Dev, Qaul, Pre-Prod and Prod.
In order to be careful when executing queries, we would like to change SQL Developer themes by connection or change the Query sheet.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is, in connection properties:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking for changing the whole theme, like change the background color to other color than plain white.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't do that, it changes the connection labels in the dropdowns and the tree, and adds a border to each editor/document associated to that connection.